# How to disable metatags for custom entity types?

Tags: meta-tags, 10

I created a custom entity type, **Fruits**.  I have the [Metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/) enabled.

I did not configure any settings to put metatags on the **Fruits** entity type, and it does not have a **Metatag** field. However, when I get a list of **Fruits** via JSON:API, a bunch of empty metatag information is output with every entity.

So, I want to disable the Metatag module tags for this entity type.  (Or, even better, I only want to add metatags to entities that I opt-in to.)

There are several issues on this, such as

- [How to disable metatag for custom entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/1429100)
- [Disable metatags by default on all entitity types, enable it only on needed and popular types - nodes, terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/1281770)
- [Option to disable meta tags per entity/bundle/object](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/1286270)

However, these are all old issues for Drupal 7, and I can't find accurate info for Drupal 8+.

How can I make sure that no metatags of any kind are added to a custom entity type?